# Twitter search API returns much fewer results than the Twitter client search engine. Why?

Tags: php, api, search, twitter

I am using the Twitter Search API with the PHP library TwitterOAuth 0.5.1 to process tweets containing a given hashtag (#citylightsorchestra for instance).

My request (see the source code below) returns only 1 result when the Web client search engine returns something like 10 tweets. Is there any way to modify my request in order to increase the result count?

```
require "twitter.config.php";
require "twitteroauth-0.5.1/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

$content = $connection->get("search/tweets",
                        array(
                          "q" => urlencode("#citylightsorchestra"),
                          "lang" => "fr",
                          "count" => "100",
                          "include_entities" => "true",
                          "result_type" => "recent"));

var_dump($content);
```

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Do you have to urlencode the `"q"` parameter? I've never used `TwitterOAuth`, but my guess is that it would do this for you. Also, are you doing the search from a twitter session with French chosen as the default language?

Comment: According the the Twitter API documentation: _Please, make sure to URL encode these queries before making the request_. As #citylightsorchestra is a digital performance that will take place in France, I only request tweets written in French as a filtering preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are (unintentionally) double-`urlencode()`ing your `q` parameter. Check out [the source of TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/src). You call `TwitterOAuth::get()`, which calls `TwitterOAuth::http()`, which in turn calls `TwitterOAuth::oAuthRequest()`, which then calls `TwitterOAuth::request()`. And after that deep call stack, we finally reach the meat of the library, the cURL calls. You should note that [internally GET variables are passed as so](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/cc4a1895f3e9b3e7ef11912e846cac479cf3497b/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L292-L297):

```
switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
            $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= '?' . Util::buildHttpQuery($postfields);
        }
        break;

    // etc...
}
```

And you'll find that in `Util::buildHttpQuery()`, [your GET parameters are escaped for you](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/cc4a1895f3e9b3e7ef11912e846cac479cf3497b/src/Util.php#L82-L114):

```
public static function buildHttpQuery($params)
{
    if (!$params) {
        return '';
    }
    // Urlencode both keys and values
    $keys = Util::urlencodeRfc3986(array_keys($params));
    $values = Util::urlencodeRfc3986(array_values($params));
    $params = array_combine($keys, $values);

    // snip...
}
```

So effectively with your code instead of sending the following encoded GET parameter:

```
q=%23citylightorchestra
```

You are double encoding and instead sending:

```
q=%2523citylightorchestra
```

So then you are searching for the exact string `%23citylightorchestra`. The fix is to simply remove your `urlencode()` and everything should work fine:

```
$content = $connection->get("search/tweets", array(
    "q" => "#citylightsorchestra",
    "lang" => "fr",
    "count" => "100",
    "include_entities" => "true",
    "result_type" => "recent"
));
```

When using a library to make calls to an API, your first stop should be the library's documentation. While the official API docs are what eventually must be obeyed, you may be unaware how your chosen library handles specific cases (like this one) and incorrectly do work that is already done for you!